# WSL PowerShell always returns Processing fstab with mount -a failed

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed WSL for my Windows 11 distribution and also Ubuntu 20.04. I saw that many people say that I can use commands without opening a distro with the `wsl` command.

Somehow that does not work for me. As soon as I type in a command with `wsl` the result is:

```
Processing fstab with mount -a failed.
```

So for example: `wsl rsync -r -v /mnt/d/DUMMY_SOURCE/ /mnt/e/DUMMY_DESTINATION`

The only wsl command that really works is `wsl -l -v`

```
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
  Ubuntu-20.04           Stopped         2
```

What is wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As I posted this question here I was already recognizing this star before the `docker-desktop-data` distro. And that is where the problem comes from.

The star here signalizes that this one is the standard distro which is wrong of course. You need to check with `wsl -l --all` which one is the current default distro. For me it was:

```
Windows Subsystem für Linux-Distributionen:
docker-desktop-data (Standard)
docker-desktop
Ubuntu-20.04
```

After that change it to the right one (for me Ubuntu):

```
wsl --setdefault Ubuntu-20.04
```

Now the commands work as they should!

Comment: This solution did not work for me with Ubuntu and Mariner (no docker-desktop) in WSL. It seems to be something else.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I had to download "Ubuntu" from the "Microsoft Store" and then I had to run it once (so that a username gets set up). Afterwards I was able to execute "wsl --setdefault Ubuntu" which then allowed me to just run the "bash" command from my Windows 11 installation. 

Comment: This did not work for me.
Output on running ```wsl -l --all``` is
```
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu-20.04 (Default)
docker-desktop-data
docker-desktop
```

But still  running ```wsl -l -v``` says ```Processing fstab with mount -a failed.```

Comment: i am still getting the same issue

Comment: It works for me. I was dealing with this issue during two days. Thanks!